# Angular 2 nested routes set root element active class

Tags: angular, routes

I've created a nested (childroutes) route in NG2 with the included router and now I want to set the main menue Item as active when a subroute is selected.

the working [plunkr with nested routes](https://plnkr.co/edit/IW7BjqyLniX6TW2njOva?p=preview) (the Plunker example need to be around 1200px width, only then you see the Menue Items - sorry for that)

My Problem is, that my main menue item need to load direktly a submenu content and so my mainmenue code looks like

```
<li routerLinkActive="active">
   <a [routerLink]="['/logviewer', 'logsuche']"  title="Logviewer">
        Logviewer
    </a>
</li>
```

and so its only shown as active, when my submenue item "logsuche" is shown

```
<li routerLinkActive="active">
     <a routerLink="/logviewer/logsuche">
        Logsuche
     </a>
</li>
```

but when I click the "logmonitor" then the mainmenue is not shown as active anymore

```
 <li routerLinkActive="active">
     <a routerLink="/logviewer/logmonitor">
         Logmonitor
     </a>
 </li>
```

Is it possible to get this working with the routing directives or did I need to write my own active directive?

my current Route config

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/logviewer/logsuche', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
      path: 'logviewer', component: LogviewerMenue,
      children: [
         { path: 'logsuche', component: LogSucheComponent },
         { path: 'logmonitor', component: LogmonitorComponent }
      ]
    }
 ];
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you actually try to accomplish, what the problem is or what the Plunker should demonstrate. You write "working plunkr" but it doesn't how anything but static text. Can you please elaborate a bit more and perhaps remove everything from the Plunker that isn't absolutely necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sorry you need to stretch the example witdth to 1200px only then you see the menue items :-/ and My Problem is, that I want to set the Main Menue Item "Logviewer" as Activated when one of the submenue Items is selected at the moment it only works for the submenue "Logsuche"

Comment: I see it now but no idea. Perhaps a custom `RouterLinkActive` directive.